# add items to global array in subshell and capture stderr/stdout

Tags: bash

I have a global var `MYLIST` and in the subsell, I want to append a string to it. Then outside the subsell, I want to log the output of the subshell (stdin/stderr) to a log file and print my list (`MYLIST`). The problem is that when I echo `"${MYLIST[@]}"` outside the subsheell the list is empty. Do you have any idea how can I get the `stderr/stdout` and also get the `MYLIST` list updated ?

```
#!/bin/bash
# File: mylist.sh
MYLIST=()
LOG="/var/log/error.log"
cmd=$(if ls -la file_not_found.txt 2>&1 ; then MYLIST+=("ls_command_success") ; else MYLIST+=("ls_command_fail") ; fi)
echo $cmd >>$LOG
echo "$cmd"
echo "${MYLIST[@]}"
```

The error is well added in the `error.log` file and I can echo the output of `$cmd`.

```
$ ./mylist.sh
Output: 
ls: cannot access 'file_not_found.txt': No such file or directory
```

Comment: `get the METRICS list updated` It's `MYLIST` in your code

Comment: @Albentrix : With respect to child processes, there is no such thing as a _global variable_, i.e. a single variable accessible from all children.  Your child process has is own variable `MYLIST`, which is not even an array, but a scalar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run not the whole if block, but only `ls` in a subshell, e.g:

```
if cmd=$(ls -la file_not_found.txt 2>&1); then
  MYLIST+=("ls_command_success")
else
  MYLIST+=("ls_command_fail")
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's simple.

```
if cmd=$(ls -la file_not_found.txt 2>&1); then
    mylist+=("ls_command_success")
else
    mylist+=("ls_command_fail")
fi
```

Notes: upper case variables are by convention reserved for exported variables like COLUMNS, `LINES`, `UID` or `PWD` etc. Prefer lowercase variables.